# SUM of 2 separate tables

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables below

Table 1

```
ID  TYPE MONTH QTY
1   I6    1     5
2   I5    2     5
3   I4    1     5
4   I6    2     5
```

Table 2

```
ID  TYPE MONTH QTY
1   I6    1     5
2   I5    1     5
3   I5    2     5
```

Desired Output (SUM of both tables)

```
TYPE MONTH1QTY MONTH2QTY
IP4    5          0
IP6    10         5
IP5    5          10
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it MySQL or Oracle?  Hover your cursor over the `sql` tags that you selected and you'll see more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the two tables are the same format it's trivial to bring both tables together using `UNION ALL` *(**NOT** just `UNION`, as that de-duplicates the data sets)*.

Then you can use `SUM(CASE WHEN)` to pivot your data.

```
SELECT
  type,
  SUM(CASE WHEN month = 1 THEN qty END)   AS month_1_qty,
  SUM(CASE WHEN month = 2 THEN qty END)   AS month_2_qty
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM table2
)
   unified_table
GROUP BY
    type
```

Note, that without dynamic SQL you have to hard code which months you want to query.  *(You can't get an extra column 'magically' appear simply because a new month appears in the data.)*

In such a case that you don't know which months you want to query, keep the data in a normalised form, then pivot it in your application / presentation layer.

```
SELECT
  type,
  month,
  SUM(qty)   AS qty
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM table2
)
   unified_table
GROUP BY
    type,
    month
```

In the event that you have different fields in each table, just be a little more specific in the `UNION ALL`.

```
(
    SELECT type, month, qty FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT type, month, qty FROM table2
)
```